# Trying to render elements with map with text that's from an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So I have an array state which keeps tracks of the text that the user has entered in the text field. What I want to render is the text embedded in a component so they can see what text they've previously entered. The problem I have is with my `Hashtags` component and when I try to render it (my attempt of it is in the ternary operator).

```
import React from "react";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { useState } from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

export default function OutlinedChips() {
  const [hashtag, setHashtag] = useState("");
  const [numberOfHashtags, setNumberOfHashtags] = useState(0);
  const [arrayOfHashtags, addHashtag] = useState([]);
  const handleDelete = () => {
    console.info("You clicked the delete icon.");
  };
  const handleHashtagChange = event => setHashtag(event.target.value);

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.info("You clicked the Chip.");
  };
  const newHashtag = () => {
    if (numberOfHashtags < 3) {
      setNumberOfHashtags(numberOfHashtags + 1);
      addHashtag(arrayOfHashtags => arrayOfHashtags.concat(hashtag));
    } else {
      console.log("Too much hashtags");
    }
  };
  const Hashtags = arrayOfHashtags.map(h => (
    <Chip
      size="small"
      avatar={<Avatar>#</Avatar>}
      label={h}
      onDelete={handleDelete}
    />
  ));
  console.log(arrayOfHashtags);
  return (
    <div>
      <TextField
        size="small"
        inputProps={{
          style: { fontSize: 15 }
        }}
        id="outlined-multiline-static"
        multiline
        rows={1}
        placeholder="Description"
        variant="outlined"
        value={hashtag}
        onChange={handleHashtagChange}
      />
      <Button color="primary" onClick={newHashtag}>
        Create!
      </Button>
      {numberOfHashtags > 0 ? <Hashtags /> : ""}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-xi9hr?file=/demo.js:0-1620

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should call Hashtags like this :

```js
{numberOfHashtags > 0 ? Hashtags : ""}
```

your Hashtags return an array, not component, so you can't call it like a component